# Removal of a vector from a basis => Resulting set doesn't span the vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose ${v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$.
Show that if any $v_{j}$ is removed from the basis, the resulting set of $n-1$ vectors does not span $V$. It seems obvious. But I do not know how to prove?

Comment: A basis is a minimally spanning and a  maximally linearly independent set according to the definitions(that you had better take a look at once more).

Comment: @MetinY. It should be *or* instead of *and*.

Comment: @GitGud Can you give me your reasoning? I could not see it at first hand.

Comment: @MetinY. A basis is a minimal spanning set. This condition is equivalent to a set being maximal linearly independent. Logically what you wrote is correct, but in my opinion it is misleading. You don't need both conditions.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose the definition of basis:

> A linearly independent spanning set for a vector space $V$ is called a basis for $V$

so if you remove the vector $v_j$ can you express this vector by a linear combination of the other vector of the basis? if your answer yes then the vectors of the basis aren't linearly independant and if your answer no then the vectors don't span the space.

Answer (score 2):

While I would recommend following the advice of Git Gud, if you still don't get it then here is the answer (hidden as a spoiler):

> Suppose not; then if the set of $n-1$ vectors is a spanning set of V, it follows that the set $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ would have to be linearly dependant, which would contradict that $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a basis of V

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Check the definition of basis.

Comment: A linearly independent spanning set for a vector space $V$ is called a basis for $V$.

Comment: I am trying to show that $v_{j}$ can not be written as a combination ${v_{1},\ldots,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},\ldots,v_{n}}$, but I don't know how.

Comment: @user81235 Andrew's answer clarifies everything.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction, suppose $\{v_1, \dots, v_{j-1}, v_{j+1}, \dots, v_n\}$ spans $V$.   We can find scalars $c_i$ not all zero such that

$$c_1v_1 + \dots + c_{j-1}v_{j-1} + c_{j+1}v_{j+1} +\dots +c_nv_n = v_j$$

Subtract $v_j$ to get

$$c_1v_1 + \dots + c_{j-1}v_{j-1} + c_{j+1}v_{j+1} +\dots +c_nv_n - v_j = 0$$

This contradicts the assumption that $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent.